# Django queryset.values_list() except returning a queryset of a foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Given some simple [models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/), including one with a foreign key:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
```

If I have an arbitrary queryset of the Entry objects, say `my_entries_queryset Entry.objects.filter(...)`.  How can I convert that into a queryset of the associated "blog" objects through the foreign key?

If I use a value_list `my_entries_queryset.values_list('blog', flat=True)` it's just a list of blog ids, not a Blog queryset that I can do further Blog-related queryset operations on.

The only way I can think of is something like this:

```
blog_ids = my_entries_queryset.values_list('blog', flat=True).distinct()
Blog.objects.filter(id__in=blog_ids)
```

But I was hoping for something more straightforward or cleaner.

EDIT

Here's what I'm going for:

```
def get_blogs_qs(entry_queryset):
   """ Return a queryset of the Blog objects from an
       arbitrary Entry queryset
   """
   # blogs_qs = ?
   return blogs_qs
```

Comment: You can also move the filters in `my_entries_queryset` to `Blog.objects.filter()`. Something like: `Blog.objects.filter(entry_set__headline='someheadline')`

Comment: The problem is this doesn't work with an arbitrary Entry queryset.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Your suggestion hard codes the entry_set, but the Entry queryset could be any, arbitrary Entry queryset, not just one specific filter.

Comment: You can add more filters then, you are not restricted to just one. So: `Blog.objects.filter(entry_set__headline='someheadline', entry_set__body_text='somebodytext')`, or even use `entry_set` to get specific entries like: `Blog.objects.filter(entry_set__in=Entry.objects.filter(<your_entry_filters>)`

Comment: Imagine this is a function that accepts an Entry qs that has been constructed elsewhere.  I want to be able to take an arbitrary Queryset on the Entry model and return a Queryset on the ForeignKey model.  But this looks promising? `Blog.objects.filter(entry_set__in=some_entry_qs)`

Comment: Yes that should work. Do note that it's only for querysets, and not singlle instances

Comment: Just to add as well, this is also possible: `Blog.objects.filter(pk__in= my_entries_queryset.values('blog'))`. No need for distinct

Answer (score 1):

This way you get a queryset with one single sentence:

```
blogs_queryseyt = Blog.objects.filter(id__in=my_entries_queryset.values_list('blog', flat=True).distinct())
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I use a value_list my_entries_queryset.values_list('blog', flat=True) it's just a list of blog ids, not a Blog queryset that I can do further Blog-related queryset operations on.

Then use [`only()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.only):

```py
for record in my_entries_queryset.only('blog'):
    print(record.blog)
```

> Blog queryset that I can do further Blog-related queryset operations

Operations like `filter()`, `annotate()`, etc are available through a related fields, so I'm not sure, why exactly you need specifically a blogs QS. But this can be done with subqueries:

```py
Blog.objects.filter(pk__in=Entries.objects.filter(...).distinct())
```